# Programmatic definition of typeof from correlation DataTable

Tags: c#, loops, datatable, typeof

Friends, I'm building a simple foreach loop that gets information from a DataTable (tblCORR) and creates 3 other DTs with it (tblCEMVALVE, tblLOG, tblNUMBER). The caveat is that it must use different column types according to what is provided in tblCORR, but of course typeof won't allow row.ItemArray[2] as the type.

tblCORR looks like this:

```
LAS.V342.B.REM.ST   V342_REM    bool    tblLOG      tblVALVE
CEM.CV44.B.REM.ST   CV44_REM    bool    tblCEMVALVE tblVALVE
CEM.FRT01.PTO06.ST  FR_PTO06    bool    tblLOG      tblSTATUS
CEM.GB02.GEAR.CTR   RR_GEAR_SEL byte    tblLOG      tblSTATUS
CEM.PT21.I_PRES.PSI PT21_PRESS  Short   tblNUMBER   tblDATA
RCP.ADD1.NAME.TXT   LAS_ADD1    string  tblNUMBER   tblLAS
```

Is there a way to do it without having to put a bunch of IFs in each case?

Thanks in advance!

```
foreach (DataRow row in tblCORR.Rows)
{
    switch (row.ItemArray[3].ToString())
    {
        case "tblCEMVALVE":
        {
            tblCEMVALVE.Columns.Add(row.ItemArray[1].ToString(), typeof(row.ItemArray[2]));
            break;
        }
        case "tblLOG":
        {
            tblLOG.Columns.Add(row.ItemArray[1].ToString(), typeof(row.ItemArray[2]));
            break;
        }
        case "tblNUMBER":
        {
            tblNUMBER.Columns.Add(row.ItemArray[1].ToString(), typeof(row.ItemArray[2]));
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With that type names (they're not name of classes/structs in `System` namespace) one possible solution is to use a `Dictionary`. For example (verbose code for illustration purposes):

```
Dictionary<object, Type> knownTypes = new Dictionary<object, Type>();
knownTypes.Add("bool", typeof(bool));
knownTypes.Add("byte", typeof(byte));
knownTypes.Add("Short", typeof(short));
knownTypes.Add("string", typeof(string));
```

To be used as:

```
tblLOG.Columns.Add(row.ItemArray[1].ToString(), knownTypes[row.ItemArray[2]]);
```

Some changes you may/should consider:

- Make dictionary a `static` and `private` class member.
- Use a typed key for dictionary (using `row.ItemArray[2].ToString()`).
- Use a case insensitive comparer `StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase` for dictionary key (if `string`) so `short` and `Short` will be equivalent.
- Use a similar technique for tables too (`tblLOG`, `tblNUMBER` and `tblCEMVALVE`) or directly search them using their `TableName` inside `DataSet`.